# Can read file from local computer, but not from IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got an MVC site that i've published to a remote server running IIS, but I've got a problem with the site where I can upload documents to a folder (on that server, within the site header folder) via the site, but I get an "Access is denied" error whenever I try to read that same document.

At first I thought it may have been a simple permissions problem, but I checked the security on the folder and it's showing full control to domain users on it, and when I run the project locally through Visual Studio I can open it up without any problems.

I assumed it may be something to do with the context of the site running under IIS, but I don't know if the changes need to be made in IIS or on the folder permissions themselves.

Can someone help?

**EDIT**

I'm opening the file using Process.Start like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FilePath");
```

**EDIT 2**

I've edited the app pool that the site is running on and set it to allow the process to interact with the desktop, but this has not worked. I have also tried setting the App Pool to load the user profile based on suggestions I found elsewhere but that has not worked either. The only other suggestion i've found is to set the App Pool identity to "Local System", but people have said this is a security risk so I don't want to do this unless necessary.

Comment: the application dn't have permissions to write to the directory

Comment: I've just reread your question. You can write the file but you can't read it?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg That's right yeah, no issues at all when I add documents, but when I try to read them I get access errors. At first I thought that it may be looking at the wrong location, but i've even hardcoded the location and it's still not working

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I've also just done another test and I can delete files via the site with no problems either, so it is just reading that's the problem

Comment: Does the "Acces is denied" error comes from the filesystem or from the website? Are you using authentication?

Comment: Can you show the code that is responsible for reading the files? It may be caused by the way the file is opened.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I'm not sure where the error is coming from, but every way I try to access it other than the website works with no error. I'm using Windows authentication for the site. I've added in the code that i'm using to open it in the main post